# Using a MultiConverter with ComboBox.SelectedValue: value for "ConvertBack" is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following scenario: In my View Model I have two properties, let them be `CreateNewThing` and `SelectedExistingThing`. `CreateNewThing` is of type `bool` and `SelectedExistingThing` is of type `Thing`.

I now have a `ComboBox` that displays two static entries, "None" and "Create new", and a list of `Thing`s. I wired it up like this:

Collection for the list of things:

```
       <ComboBox.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="AllThings" Source="{Binding ViewModel.AllThings, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyCustomControl}}}" />
            <tools:ThingSelector x:Key="ThingSelector" />
        </ComboBox.Resources>
```

Setup for the `ItemsSource`:

```
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <tools:PlaceholderForNone />
                <tools:PlaceholderForNew />
                <Separator />
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource AllThings}}" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
```

Binding for `SelectedValue`:

```
        <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ThingSelector}">
                <Binding Path="ViewModel.CreateNewThing" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyCustomControl}}" />
                <Binding Path="ViewModel.SelectedExistingThing" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyCustomControl}}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
```

My `ThingSelector` looks like this:

```
internal sealed class ThingSelector: IMultiValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if((values == null) ||
           (values.Length != 2) ||
           (!(values[0] is bool))) {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
        if((bool)values[0]) {
            return new PlaceholderForNew();
        }
        if(values[1] is Thing) {
            return values[1];
        }
        return new PlaceholderForNone();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if(value is PlaceholderForNew) {
            return new object[] { true, null };
        }
        return new object[] { false, value as Thing};
    }
}
```

The `PlaceholderForXXX` are done in a way that their `HashCode` is always 0 and `Equals` is `true` for all objects of the same type, so all two `PlaceholderForXXX` are equal.

The strange thing is now: I can select the "None" and "Create new" options from my combo box, and they are correctly propagated (i.e., selecting the "new" option sets the `CreateNewThing` property to `true` and the `SelectedExistingThing` property to `null`).
However, when I select a `Thing` from the combo box, the `ConvertBack` method is invoked with the parameter `value` being `null` where, to my understanding, it should be the selected value of the `ComboBox` which is clearly not `null` (if I put an appropriate event into the code-behind, I really see that `SelectedValue` is a `Thing` and not null).

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes it is, I corrected it.

Comment: I copied your code, and when I select a `Thing` in the combobox, I get the selected `Thing` as the `value` parameter to `ConvertBack`. I had to write my own viewmodel, but I can't find a way to break that which reproduces the behavior you're seeing.